# Mahapps metro window title

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I am using MahApps.Metro `MetroWindow`.

I'm assigning my title in the following way:

```
Title="My Application"
```

But it is showing the title as "MY APPLICATION".

I have cross verified it by setting the `Title` to "My", but it shows "MY".

Hope I need to set some property attribute to fix this.

Comment: That's probably in the template, which means you'd have to change the template to fix.  Which wouldn't be hard.  Simply fork the repo on github, make the change, and use that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply set the TitleCaps property of the window to false

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MahApps.Metro.Simple.Demo.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                  Title="MainWindow"
                  Height="200"
                  Width="600"
                  TitleCaps="False">
```

That should be it.